# Azure Policy schema-like evaluation

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have a task to create a notification system where I can configure which email goes when based on conditions.
Since I would like it to be multi-tenant and customizable I thought that the conditions could be stored/configured in the same manner as Azure Policy json.
For my system I need:

- conditions
- parameter replacing

In "then" statement I would point to the notification id.

Is there any out-of-the-box library that I could use for evaluation of this kind of jsons?
Or my only option is to look at the source code of AZ Policy and create such a thing myself.

Thanks,
Rafal

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this would not be possible with policy since policy does not support notification systems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually do not want to use AZ Policy per se here, but I would like to create a different system (notifications, but could be whatever) that would be configurable to the same extent as the Policies. 
I just like the syntax of the JSON used for the Policies and I would be keen to use similar syntax for my app. 
Thus I am asking if there is any library that could do this JSON syntax parsing for me and I could base my system on it. If I am to write it myself, I at least know I do not reinvent the wheel.